# One view containing part of another view in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to create an app with SpriteKit. I am intending to have a main `SKView` and another view in the corner that displays part of the main `SKView` up close. The view in the corner would have no purpose other than to display up close a part of the main `SKView`. I can't seem to find any sort of class or function that does this. I also haven't found a similar question on Stack Overflow or any other question-answer site.

It doesn't really matter what type of view the corner view is. The main view does need to be an `SKView`. Apart from that, there are no other specifications I can think of. Is there a way to mirror part of one `SKView` to another view?

Comment: Try with SKNodes inside of only one view, make minimap as a SKTexture of another SKNode :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based off Maetschl's comment above.

This is possible with `SKTexture`. In your `SKScene`, add a `SKSpriteNode` named textureNode or something similar. In the `didMove()`, initialize it with a blank initializer and set basic properties. Your `SKScene` class should look like this

```
var textureNode : SKSpriteNode!
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    textureNode = SKSpriteNode()
    textureNode.position = .zero
    textureNode.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
    addChild(textureNode)
}
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    textureNode.texture = view?.texture(from: self) //Makes the new node display the scene
}
```

What this does is has a node display the scene. What the node shows changes based on what the scene's texture is. Again, thanks to Maetschl for the inspiration.

Comment: While this technically works, it's going to be useless for the vast majority of developers, as the performance hit for calling `texture(from:)` is significant -- especially when calling it every frame, as done here. I'm sure the complexity of the scene being rendered is relevant, as is the size of the crop used, but it's still pretty useless for anything but static content.